# Логин/Пароль GitHub в PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm

я не верно ввел логин/пароль в гит и он там сохранился. При клике Log in via GitHub, как на фото 1 сразу открывается браузер и сообщает об ошибке, на фото 2. Подскажите, где хранятся данные логин/пароль и как их поправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В настройках винды было какое-то хранилище учетных данных - не там?

Comment: Нет, не было, кроме того, в учетке записей PyCharm вообще нет